# Tensorflow 2.x: CPU/GPU Benchmark, GPU seems slower

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My GPU seems slower than standard CPU.

Windows 10, Tensorflow 2.4, GeForce MX130, Conda

my nvidia-smi output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 452.25       Driver Version: 451.82       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX130      WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P8    N/A /  N/A |   1196MiB /  2048MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

my tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') output,

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I used memory_growth for the GPU, otherwise it has error like "InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed".

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

When I used an MNIST model to train on GPU,

```
t=time.time()
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
print('GPU Time: ', time.time()-t)
```

it returns,

```
1875/1875 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0740 - accuracy: 0.9759
GPU Time:  31.825101613998413
```

And, when I ran the same on CPU, it takes less time.

```
t=time.time()
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
print('CPU Time: ', time.time()-t)
```

It returns,

```
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0747 - accuracy: 0.9773
CPU Time:  13.330947875976562
```

What am I missing? Should I try CNN for testing the parallel processing?

Thank you.

Comment: One possible issue might be if your Windows display driver is using the GPU, TensorFlow will have to be sharing the GPU with the driver. `nvidia-smi` (on Linux at least) reports percentage of time used by each process, so that might give you a clue. This also might help identify if there is a bottleneck - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. My laptop has 2 GPU, I believe one being the NVIDIA and another is Intel. When I use the GPU, specifically using the with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'), it's not being significantly used.

Comment: When I use the anaconda powershell with, 

python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

It goes to 100% GPU usage spike for the NVIDIA.

Comment: What you are missing is that not all computations are faster in the GPU than the CPU, your model is quite small so its using a very low percentage of the GPUs capacity.

Comment: GPU faster than a CPU depends on things like the size of the data you’re working on and how computationally intense the code is. Small data with few calculations is a poor fit for a GPU. Thanks!